# Javascript Post-Render Selection by Value not updating dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down list of options which lets my users choose one of a few options. But I want to also include a button that when pressed will select a specific option out of the dropdown list.

This is working but the issue is that the dropdown list isnt showing the updated selection, but if you click on the dropdown list you can see that the selection the button chose is highlighted and is indeed selected.

```js
function onclick() {
  document.form.server_select.value = 'Quebec';
}
```

```html
<select name="server_select" id="server_select">
  <option value="random" selected>Auto Select</option>
  <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
  <option value="NewYork">NewYork</option>
  <option value="Seattle">Seattle</option>
  <option value="France">France</option>
</select>


<button onclick="onclick()">Button</button>
```

---

When you load the page the first option is displayed in the drop down to the user as seen [image: Here]

and

[image: Here]

After pressing the button the dropdown still shows the first option in the list but when clicking onto the dropdown you can see a different option is selected.
[image: Still showing Auto Select] [image: Still showing Auto Select even though Quebec is selected]

I expected the dropdown to also show the new selection.

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide an executable snippet. So that it eliminates the need to individually test it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works as expected:

```js
function change() {
    document.getElementById('server_select').value = 'Quebec';
}
```

```html
<form>
<select name="server_select" id="server_select">
    <option value="random" selected>Auto Select</option>
    <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
    <option value="NewYork">NewYork</option>
    <option value="Seattle">Seattle</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
</select>
</form>
<button onclick="change()">Button</button>
```

But looking at the screenshots, it looks like they are doing a custom dropdown, basically you are clicking on a transparent select, and they are updating their pretty dropdown manually, something like this:

```js
function change() {
    document.getElementById('server_select').value = 'Quebec';
}

function change2() {
    element = document.getElementById('server_select')
    element.value = 'Quebec';
    var event;
    event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    event.initMouseEvent('change', true, true, window);
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function open() {
    document.getElementById('server_select').value = 'Quebec';
}

document.getElementById('server_select').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
       document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = event.target.value
})
```

```css
#dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
#server_select {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
<div id="dropdown">
    <span id="value">Auto Select</span>
    <select name="server_select" id="server_select">
      <option value="random" selected>Auto Select</option>
      <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
      <option value="NewYork">NewYork</option>
      <option value="Seattle">Seattle</option>
      <option value="France">France</option>
    </select>
</div>

</form>
<button onclick="change()">Button</button>
<button onclick="change2()">Button Fixed</button>
```

You'll have to look at the actual HTML structure of your document to see what you need to update, but use the Button Fixed example to see (basically) what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using reserved words such as `onclick` as function name

for list of reserved words please look into https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

```js
function change() {
  document.getElementById("server_select").value  = "Quebec";
}
```

```html
<select name="server_select" id="server_select">
    <option value="random" selected>Auto Select</option>
    <option value="Quebec">Quebec</option>
    <option value="NewYork">NewYork</option>
    <option value="Seattle">Seattle</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
</select>


<button onClick="change()">Button</button>

<script>

</script>
```